# How can I convert the code System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy() to be used in VBA?

Tags: vba

I am working on a VBA program and I have got the following code in VB.NET:

```
    Private Function SYS_GuidPtrToGuid(ByVal p As System.IntPtr) As System.Guid
        Dim b(15) As Byte
        Dim myGuid As System.Guid
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(p, b, 0, b.Length)
        myGuid = New System.Guid(b)
        Erase b
        Return myGuid
    End Function
```

Do I need to rewrite the code or is there any other functions that I can use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first determine what `Guid` classes are available to you and if they don't provide a method to receive a GUID from a pointer, but do work with a `Byte` array like the .NET `Guid`, then you need to convert the `Marshal.Copy` call to a `MemCpy` call using

```
Declare Sub MemCpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination() As Byte, ByVal SourcePtr As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
```

Note I've adjusted the `MemCpy` declaration to expect a pointer already converted to a `Long` and to copy to a `Byte` array.

So, your code could be (but remember I haven't checked what `Guid` classes are available to you):

```
Private Function SYS_GuidPtrToGuid(ByVal p As Long) As Guid
    Dim b(15) As Byte
    MemCpy b, p, UBound(b) - LBound(b) + 1
    SYS_GuidPtrToGuid = New Guid(b)
End Function
```

Given your comment here's a `MemCpy` declaration to copy from a `Long` pointer directly to a `guid`.

```
Declare Sub MemCpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByRef Destination As GUID, ByVal SourcePtr As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
```

And now the call is simply:

```
Private Function SYS_GuidPtrToGuid(ByVal p As Long) As Guid
    MemCpy SYS_GuidPtrToGuid, p, 16
End Function
```

This does depend upon the `guid` packing being right, but that's the point of the `Type`.

Comment: How about if guid is not a class but defined as type?
`Public Type guid
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type`

Then I can't use the "new" keyword, right?
And How can I write the values to all these fields?
Thanks!!